# Will data become unrecoverable if I force write partition structure?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I am planning to use the "write" the partition structure option available in testdisk.  There is a chance that this structure is wrong.  **In that case will any of my raw data get overwritten if I write the structure?**

I have used easeus to see if the **raw data is still present.**  It is.  But easeus cannot find the directory structure.  It can only find the raw files and some of the folder structures.

**Background** :
It was a perfectly working 3 tb disk.  **Resized** it using paragon.  Failed.  Windows sees the disk as disk with 2.7tb and .3 tb.

**Possible issue** :a I **assume** paragon has **not** created the new partition yet.  It was just moving the files, so that it can free up space.  But **somehow** windows is finding two logical disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It will only write the MBR and wont affect any of the other sectors.

I took a risk and selected "write".  Before I did that, I clicked 'P', this listed my directory structure so I was comfortable that testdisk has indeed found my structur.

I have got my data back.

Comment: Great. You should accept your own answer. Also: it's always a great idea to have a copy of the disk you're trying to recover. You can use `dd` or `ddrescue` to make the image depending on whether the disk operates properly (no bad sectors) or not, respectively.